# Nested While Loops Issues in PHP

Tags: php, sql, excel

i have a database of sports, i have 2 tables one for events and one for odds . i have successfully fetched the data from  the events table , i am trying to fetch odds for each of those events that have been retrieved from the database, but it takes forever to load ,probably because i am using multiple while loops, Please how can i simplify the sql query to reduce the load time . Here is my code below

```
<?php
    include("admin/db.php");
    include("../mpdf.php");
     $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8',    // mode - default ''
     'A4-L',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
     12,     // font size - default 0
     '',    // default font family
     2,    // margin_left
     2,    // margin right
     2,     // margin top
     2,    // margin bottom
     0,     // margin header
     0,     // margin footer
     'L');  // L - landscape, P - portrait 

    $html .="<h1 align='center'>ELSPORTBET</h1>";
    $html .="<table border=1 width='100%;' cellpadding=1>";

    $stmt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY league limit 100");

    $current_cat = null;
    while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($stmt)) {
      if ($row["league"] != $current_cat) {
        $current_cat = $row["league"];
        $html.="<tr><th colspan='3' align='center'>$current_cat</th></tr>";
      }
      $html.="<tr><td colspan='3' align='center'>$row[eventid]</td>";

     /* planning to call a while loop here , takes forever to load
     $sql4=mysql_query("select price from odds where eventid='$row[eventid]'");
      while($odds=mysql_fetch_array($sql4)){
        $html.="<tr><td colspan='3' align='center'>$odds[price]</td></tr>";  output all the odds
      } */

    }
    $html .="</table>";

    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $stylesheet = file_get_contents('table_style.css');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);    
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output("pdf.pdf", "I");
    exit;

?>
```

Comment: For one thing, remove the quotes for `ORDER BY 'league'` this is a column and not a value.

Comment: ok thanks , i have done just that

Comment: Can't see any nested while loops in your code.

Comment: (Sidenote) Usually, when starting a concatenation (string), the first dot doesn't need to be there. So instead of `$html .="<h1 align='center'>ELSPORTBET</h1>";` remove it `$html ="<h1 align='center'>ELSPORTBET</h1>";` unsure if it will help speed it up or not. You could also try switching to `mysqli_` or PDO which might speed it up a tad and/or look into doing pagination.

Comment: what is the best way to fetch the data from the other table , as the second query depends on the first while loop

Comment: See the answer below; it makes sense. (About you're calling the DB for each query). I've seen that be the problem before (just remembered it now).

Comment: @Charlesliam What's with the edit? You just deleted 1/2 the OP's code. I am doing a rollback; **please don't do that again,** unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @Fred,I know php, writing to pdf and sql. His only asking for sql performance. DO you think writing result to pdf is connected to sql performance?

Comment: @Fred,Did u see Ryan define anything to what I deleted code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're calling the DB for every single query. Why not do something like (The "," is an inner join):

```
$stmt = mysql_query("SELECT e.league, o.price FROM event e, odds o WHERE e.eventid = o.eventid ORDER BY e.league limit 100");

$current_cat = null;
$current_id = null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($stmt)) {
  if ($row["league"] != $current_cat) {
    $current_cat = $row["league"];
    $html .= "<tr><th colspan='2' align='center'>$current_cat</th></tr>";
    $html .= "<tr><td align='center'>$row[eventid]</td>";
    $html .= "<td align='center'>$row[price]</td></tr>"; 
  }
  else
  {
    if($row["eventid"] != $current_id)
    {
       $current_id = $row["eventid"];
       $html .= "</tr><tr><td align='center'>$current_id</td>";
       $html .= "<td align='center'>$row[price]</td>";
    }
    else
    {
    $html .= "<td align='center'>$row[price]</td>"; 
    }
  }
}
$html .="</tr>";
```

OK that should work.

Comment: The code you had written creates a table that contains rows with ids and prices. What would you like to see instead? Would you like a blank cell in place of the id? I'll edit the answer to contain that until I know exactly what you're looking for

Comment: ok @Ryan, everything is fine except that i want the price of the products to be in an individual TD horizontally alligned e.g  ID2 | $52 | $32 | $33

Comment: Edited answer per comment